# Use google maps API to calculate distance between lat-longs in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps

I have a pandas dataframe, the snippet of which looks like this:

```
test
latitude   longitude
17.355282  99.149210
17.355282  99.149210
17.355377  99.149220
17.355377  99.149220
17.355300  99.149280
17.355389  99.149254
```

I wish to have a new column, say, 'distance' which calculates distance between each successive entry using googlemaps API in python.

I have written a function like this:

```
def calculate_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):

    distance = gmaps.distance_matrix([str(lat1) + " " + str(lon1)], 
                                 [str(lat2) + " " + str(lon2)], 
                                 mode='walking')['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'].split(' ')[0]
    return distance
```

When I called this function:

```
calculate_distance(test.latitude.values, test.longitude.values,
                 test.loc[1:, 'latitude'].values, test.loc[1:, 'longitude'].values)
```

I get this response:

```
{'status': 'NOT_FOUND'}
```

I also added a shift function to my first lat-long upon calling the function as folows:

```
calculate_distance(test.latitude.shift(), test.longitude.shift(),
                 test.loc[1:, 'latitude'].values, test.loc[1:, 'longitude'].values)
```

It puts `nan` value in the first entry and it gives the following KeyError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-199-8da29743b4a6> in <module>
      1 calculate_distance(test.latitude.shift(), test.longitude.shift(),
----> 2                  test.loc[1:, 'latitude'].values, test.loc[1:, 'longitude'].values)

<ipython-input-198-64f14b39eec4> in calculate_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
     11     distance = gmaps.distance_matrix([str(lat1) + " " + str(lon1)], 
     12                                  [str(lat2) + " " + str(lon2)],
---> 13                                  mode='walking')['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'].split(' ')[0]
     14     return distance
     15 

KeyError: 'distance'
```

I verified the API, its working using the first two lat longs:

```
distance = gmaps.distance_matrix([str(17.355282) + " " + str(99.14921)], 
                                 [str(17.355282) + " " + str(99.149210)], 
                                 mode='walking')['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']

distance
'1 m'
```

What went wrong here? Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new columns by [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and then call function in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) without missing values:

```
test[['lat_shifted','long_shifted']] = test[['latitude','longitude']].shift(-1)


f = lambda x: calculate_distance(x['lat_shifted'], x['long_shifted'], x['latitude'], x['longitude'])
test['new'] = test.dropna().apply(f, axis = 1)
```